# How to access a host on 192.0.2.0/24 from Linux?

Tags: networking, centos, routing, switch

I've got my hands on the FSM-510G switch that has a default IP set to 192.0.2.1.
It's obviously not in the LAN CIDR block, so what should I do on a Linux host to be able to access it directly?

The Linux host runs CentOS 7 and is connected to the switch directly (eth1 interface).

Comment: **It's obviously not in the LAN CIDR block** - Why would that be obvious? We don't know your network. **What should I do on a Linux host to be able to access it directly?** - Assign the Linux host an ip address/subnet mask in the same subnet as the switch.

Comment: Odd. I thought keeping LANs to 192.168. and 10.8. was more then just a convention.
Thanks, I'll do just that.

Comment: Bizarre. I looked at the [manual](http://ftp.icpdas.com.tw/pub/cd/ethernetswitch/napdos/fsm-510g/FSM-510G_QuickStart_1.0.pdf) and it actually ships from the factory with that IP address! Note that this network is defined in [RFC 5735](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735). It's a technically legitimate but very unusual usage.

Comment: See the _[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)_. Only the blocks that are Reserved-by-Protocol require special handling by all IPv4 implementations (recognized by IPv4 itself). IPv4 has no distinction between private and public addresses.